# Style cop strange error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, stylecop, stylecop-plus

I am using style cop and getting an error in vs 2015 for my c# code

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     SP2001 : StyleCopPlus.StyleCopPlus : Only tab characters are
>   allowed to be used for
>   indentation.

So I have selected the content and Go to

> Edit >> Advanced >> Tabify the selected lines

And run style cop and getting the error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     SA1027 : CSharp.Spacing : Tabs are not allowed. Use spaces
>   instead.

I don't know how to solve it, Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have corrected it by refering this [document](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Managing%20StyleCop%20Project%20Settings)

I have disabled rule SA1027: TabsMustNotBeUsed in the spacing rules

And I have untabiy the code.

Comment: What I want keep using spaces? Do you know how to disable SP2001 rule?